# German invoicing practices

Tags: accounting, germany

I'm based in the UK, and recently started buying services from a German company ([Contabo](https://contabo.com/en/)). I'm paying from a Euro card account, and they have a UK VAT registration, so there are no complications with either currency exchange or VAT.

The problem is that they issue invoices that do not match the deductions from my card account. Over the first 3 months they took:

```
19th Jun 14.38
13th Jul  8.62
13th Aug  8.62
```

And they invoiced:

```
30th Jun 15.81
31st Jul  8.62
31st Aug  7.19
```

Note that it reconciles after 3 months. I've had a back-and-forth with their support department, who won't involve their accounts department. Support tells me that the invoices match a running total (true) at some point in time, and say they do pre-authorisations early, and so on, but they also say that my statement that "*an invoice must always exactly match the sum requested or already taken*" is "*not always true*".

Sanity check: surely this is nonsense? Is it universally true that "an invoice must always exactly match the sum requested or already taken"? Or are these not real invoices, and perhaps a pro-forma of some sort? It says it's an invoice, and has their bank A/C and court details, and so on, and has a VAT number on it (but it's a UK VAT number).

Comment: Are these *invoices* or *receipts*?

Comment: @littleadv: invoices.

Comment: Invoice is what they want you to pay. Receipt is the documentation of what you actually paid. Did you get receipts matching the charges?

Comment: @littleadv: they send a variety of emails: for instance, on Aug 13, they said they had pre-authorised 8.62, and on Aug 19 they said they had deducted 8.62. Correct. However, these are next to useless from an accounting point of view: (a) I need a valid "VAT invoice" to claim back the tax (true in both the UK and the EU), and (b) I can't give my accountant piles of printed-out emails at year end. You have to do legally-defined invoicing to run a VAT-registered business in the UK, so my Q is a sanity check: is this also true in Germany?

Comment: That's not really personal finance, so is offtopic here. As a general rule - yes, it's true everywhere.

Comment: "I can't give my accountant piles of printed-out emails at year end." if they are relevant documents for the bookkeeping, you'll have to hand them to your accountant - otherwise, how should they do the accounting properly? However, they may be able to do without the receipts and use your account statements instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my 2 ct, I'm not an accountant, just running a business in Germany.

---

Preliminary side thought: why do you get VAT on your invoice anyways? AFAIK, for B2B transactions the VAT reverse charge procedure is still in place between EU and UK. (They need the UK VAT number for private customers in the UK)

I.e., you should receive (and pay) invoices *without* VAT.

---

Really, you need to ask your accountant about this. But my take on the situation is that when invoice and account movements deviate* either a liability or accounts receivable are created. The invoice states the sum requested, but it does not necessarily match the sum received (the thing that must match here is the receipt or your account statement).
In your case, you got an invoice and basically made a down payment on it, which turned out to not precisely match after all.
This is not all that unusual. Think e.g. of a plumber. They send you an offer, you give them the go and you agree on a down-payment of amount x. For which you get a receipt, and they start plumbing. After they are done, they send you the invoice with amount y. You pay the difference y - x, and then the account is settled.

*which they do regularly for businesses under imputed taxation (Soll-Besteuerung) where the date of delivery and payment dates rarely match.
Since you do not recognize the situation, I guess you are under actual taxation (Ist-Besteuerung) instead, where you can mostly avoid this hassle since the date of the payment is used instead of the delivery/service date.

And yes, how you account for such happenings is legally well-defined in Germany as well. But the precise accounting procedures differ depending on whether you are under imputed or actual taxation.
Since your service provider is likely under imputed taxation the situation doesn't even create more bookkeeping work for them. OTOH, you may need to create a liability here as well and then cancel it with the payment 3 months later, and thus may not be able to use the shortcut of never creating the liability.

Comment: I think you're right on the liability and accounts receivable thing. It's a major headache for such small sums, and completely avoidable. I've given up asking my accountant questions. In 30+ years with different accountants I don't think I've ever got a simple straight answer that I could understand.

Comment: On VAT: foreign suppliers can register for a UK VAT number (in this case, I think the single number is valid in both countries). When you do this, the reverse charge is no longer necessary. It's primarily useful for supplies to end-users, not businesses, because it's no longer necessary to charge VAT on entry to the UK. I remember a Scandinavian supplier on the radio last year complaining about how complicated it was to do this. For B2B, the whole VAT thing is completely pointless, because the net result is zero. It exists so that governments can track cross-border trade...

Comment: ...but the UK VAT form no longer has a box for cross-border trade (only NI movements). It's so stupid that I frequently ignore VAT on cross-border invoices, *unless* the supplier has a UK VAT number, and has already charged me, in which case I have to claim it back.